# Azure mobileservice with winforms

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services

I am trying to insert data in a SQL database using Microsoft Azure Mobile Service.

Unfortunately I did not succeed with this and have not found any code that works.

Is there anyone who tested it and got it to work?

All i want to do is insert rows into the same table Azure SQL as my Mobile Service.

.

EDIT PROBLEM SOLVED!

```c#
public static MobileServiceClient MobileService = new MobileServiceClient(
  "https://YOUR-DOMAIN.azure-mobile.net/",
  "YOUR-KEY"
);

public class Item
{
  public string Id { get; set; }
  public string Text { get; set; }
}

private void buttonInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Item item = new Item { Text = "Awesome item" };
  MobileService.GetTable<Item>().InsertAsync(item);
}
```

Comment: How did you do it with WinForms? As I know there is no official Azure mobile app SDK for WinForms. They have for Windows Store apps for desktop.

Comment: I add the DLL-files to the project then used the code above. You need to know about asynctasks to be able to use some of the functions. I used the store apps SDK and modified the example code in the Azure api to work with winforms.

Comment: I was able to initialize the MobileServiceClient but the InsertAsync call (or other calls on the table like ToEnumerableAsync) fails raising an exception with "Thread aborted" message. Any suggestion?